# Spray: query as part of URI or parameter

Tags: scala, rest, spray

I try to allow two types of usage for an API: Either provide query as part of the URI or provide it as a parameter.

## Endpoints

`/search/myQuery` equivalent to `/search?query=myQuery`

both should return the same result.

## Code

here is the implmentation I am currently using. It feels a little climsy though, as a lot of the code needs to be repeated.

```
path("search") {
  parameter('query) { term =>
    get {
     complete { performSearch(term) }
    }
} ~
path("search" / Segment) { searchTerm =>
  get {
    complete { performSearch(term) }
  }
}
```

## Question

Is there a more DRY way to express this behaviour in Spray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spray has very strong combinators so it is very trivial task.

```
val pathOrParameter = path(Segment) | parameter('search)

path("search") {
  pathOrParameter { term =>
    get {
     complete { performSearch(term) }
    }
  }
}
```

In addition to that you can combine further like:

```
val searchApi = get & path("search") & (path(Segment) | parameter('search))

searchApi { term =>
  complete { performSearch(term) }
}
```

[Custom Directive](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-routing/advanced-topics/custom-directives/) page explains spray's ability to compose directives in detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I tried as you described before allready, but without the parens `(path(Segment) | parameter('search))`it wouldn't compile.
`

Comment: It is typesafe so if types are different, it won't compile. For example `get` has type `Directive0` and `parameter('search)` has type `Directive1[String]` so `get | parameter('search)` won't compile.

Comment: Link to "Custom Directive" page returns 404 :(